# Function returns a value, how to get a string value instead

Tags: javascript

`javascript` beginner here. I searched for a solution for a long time but couldn't find a solution. Please give an answer if you can. Thank you.

computerSelection function returns a value. I want a string value here. When I added debugger it shows `computerSelection = ƒ ()`. So even if `(computerSelection === "paper")` it doesn't alert "match draw".

```js
function gamePlay () {       
    let gameSelections = ["rock","paper","scissor"];

    let computerSelection = function () {
        function getRandomSelection() {
            return gameSelections[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        }
        return getRandomSelection();
    }


    console.log(computerSelection());
    //  when I added debugger; and ran the code in developer options it shows --computerSelection = ƒ ()--. So even if (computerSelection === "paper") it doesn't alert "match draw".

    if (computerSelection === "paper") {
        alert("match draw");
    }
}

gamePlay();
```

I found a way that works. But, I still want to understand the reason behind why it didn't work before and why it works now.

```js
function gamePlay () {
    let gameSelections = ["rock","paper","scissor"];

    let computerSelection =  function () {
        function getRandomSelection() {
            return gameSelections[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) ] ;
        }
        return getRandomSelection();
    }

    let computerSelectionStringValue = computerSelection();

    console.log(computerSelectionStringValue);
    //  this time when added debugger in developer options it shows --computerSelectionStringValue = "paper"-- 

    if (computerSelectionStringValue === "paper") {
        alert("match draw");
    }
}

gamePlay();
```

Comment: I tried both your code block, both worked for me

Comment: `computerSelection` is a function. `computerSelection()` calls the function and returns its return value, a string. `computerSelection` = `ƒ`. `computerSelection()` = `"paper"`

Comment: computerSelection can return a different value every time it is called

Comment: You need to call the function `computerSelection()` with `()` in the `if` condition. Also, why is `getRandomSelection` function even required? Just return the random value directly from `computerSelection`

Answer (score 0):

you are getting confused as to what computerSelection is. you are expecting it to be both the function and the result of the function.

think of your result this way:

```
let result = computerSelection();
```

or:

```
if (computerSelection() == 'rock') { ... }
```